# Date field and Jquery UI date picker - start date - end date

Tags: webforms, javascript, datetime

I'm not sure if this could be considered an issue, but I cannot find anywhere relevant in forum to pose the question.

I am trying to understand how webforms works with Jquery UI and date picker. My objective is to be able to manipulate what happens with the Jquery UI date picker element. Although things are working in the interface, when I submit the form the data is not being saved.

If anybody could point out where I am going wrong and point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

here is my problem :

I have two date fields. and arrival date and a departure date. I want to be able to refresh/rewrite value of departure date based on what has been selected for the arrival date.

I have added the following code to a js file which is called by the page :

```
(function ($) { 
  Drupal.behaviors.localeDatepicker = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      jQuery("#edit-submitted-arrivee").datepicker({
        onSelect: function (date) {
          var date2 = jQuery('#edit-submitted-arrivee').datepicker('getDate');
          date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 2);
          jQuery('#edit-submitted-depart').datepicker('setDate', date2);
          //sets minDate to edit-submitted-arrivee date  1
          jQuery('#edit-submitted-depart').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);
        }
      });
      jQuery("#edit-submitted-depart").datepicker({
        onClose: function () {
          var date2 = jQuery('#edit-submitted-arrivee').datepicker('getDate');
          console.log(edit-submitted-arrivee);
          var date1 = jQuery('#edit-submitted-depart').datepicker('getDate');
          if (date1 <= date2) {
            var minDate = jQuery('#edit-submitted-depart').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
            jQuery('#edit-submitted-depart').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };
}(jQuery));
```

As I said everything works ok in the browser for the user... but when the form is submitted the values for the dates are not passed to the submissions table.... is there something wrong with the way I call Drupal.behaviors.localeDatepicker or is there something with onSelect: function (date) I should be noticing?

thanks in advance for any suggestions.